# Connect from Hosted Web App to Server Application using Secure Features?

Tags: javascript, c#, http, websocket, https

Hopefully the title makes some sense!
I'm struggling with the following problem:

I have a desktop app built with C# and Unity.  I need to communicate from a web app back to this desktop app in the most straightforward way possible with as little latency as possible - *over a local network.* (I do not need any further networking, because both the mobile app and the desktop app will be running on the same network)
The challenge is HTTP(s) and Websockets.

It doesn't matter to me if I need to self-host the web app over local network, or host it online somewhere, I'm flexible.
I tried hosting the webpage directly from the c# app using HTTPListener, and that worked great and allowed for easy websocket communication, but because I need to use the web app device's sensors (Gyro, etc), I need to be on HTTPS (from my understanding.  Any way around that?)

When I try hosting the web app over HTTPS (using Live Server in VSCode), the sensors work, but I then can't interact with the unsecured WebSocket Server also being hosted via the C# app because an HTTPS site can't communicate with a non WSS Websocket.

The question is:  What are my options?  How can I work around these issues in a way that allows me to easily build the Unity app and distribute it without needing any additional headache.  Same goes for the web app.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

For reference, my C# code is as follows:

```
public class HTTPScript : MonoBehaviourRect
{
    private HttpListener httpListener;
    public int port;
    public string filePath;
    public WebSocketServer wsServer;

    private void Start()
    {
        filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, filePath);
        // Create the HttpListener and add the URL for hosting the webpage
        httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:{port}/");

        try
        {
            // Start the HttpListener
            httpListener.Start();
            Debug.Log("Webpage hosting started.");

            // Begin listening for incoming requests
            httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleIncomingRequest, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error starting HttpListener: {e.Message}");
        }

        wsServer = new WebSocketServer(port+1);
        wsServer.AddWebSocketService<MyWebSocketBehavior>("/ws");
        wsServer.Start();
        Debug.Log($"WebSocket server started on port {port+1}");
    }

    private void HandleIncomingRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = httpListener.EndGetContext(result);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Permissions-Policy", "gyroscope=*, accelerometer=*, geolocation=*, magnetometer=*, microphone=*, camera=*");

            string responseString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();

            // Begin listening for the next incoming request
            httpListener.BeginGetContext(HandleIncomingRequest, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error handling incoming request: {e.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (httpListener != null)
        {
            try
            {
                httpListener.Stop();
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}


public class MyWebSocketBehavior : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = e.Data; 
        Debug.Log(e.Data);
    }
}
```